# Does git checkout overwrite all files?

Tags: git, laravel, web-applications, version-control, octobercms

I currently have this sort of a setup for my web app

1. Development copy of app in laptop which is where I do all the coding.
2. A bare repo (using **git init --bare** in /projects/test.git folder of my web server). Also, I added a post-recieve.

As

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/public_html/projects/test git checkout -f
```

3. I make changes in my laptop. Do a **git add .**, **git commit** and **git push web master**.

My question is would it reset the files at /public_html/projects/test to keep it sync with the development repo or would it merely push the changes. This question is that when people upload content / submit stuff on the web app it adds to the /public_html/projects/test/uploads folder and my worry is whether it would replace the content of the uploads with my development copy each time. Also, I cannot add /uploads to .git_ignore as when I do some upload via the development machine and then do the push I want those files to get added to the public_html production version as well. So, how does this `git checkout -f` work?

Comment: related: [Does git checkout update all files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214691/does-git-checkout-update-all-files)

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -f` has two values:

1. It returns files that at git tree to HEAD
2. It hide from you list of file that modify when you change branch for files at git tree

If file or folder stay at git ignore you can manually add it to git tree by `git add -f`. So it might be helpfully for developer machine.